# How to disable "allow xxx to run 'microsoft office'"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, browsers

I have a publishing site on SP 2013. When viewed with Firefox, users get a message:

> Allow `site.xzy.com` to run "Microsoft Office?

How do I disable this?

I thought this was the "client integration" setting, and have already disabled that, but the message still appears.

edit: as noted below, I want to disable this so it doesn't appear for any users. It's a publishing site, and users will not be interacting with office docs of any kind.

Comment: As Moe mentioned, to disable this alert You need to always active the Microsoft Office 2013 15.0.4420.1017 Plugins. The plugin allows you to have a better experience with Microsoft SharePoint.

Comment: This is a publishing site that will be viewed by non-employees. I don't want a permissions pop up confusing and distracting the users. And I don't want to have to send out a message to 1000 non employees with special instructions so they can view a website. Again, it's just a publishing site; they will not be using any MS office functionality by design.

Comment: I dont think then you can do this...The only place you can get the anwser is Contact MSFT support for this.

Answer (score 3):

Got it. Add the following script to the head to override the functions that add the activex:

```
//get rid of name.dll reference 
function ProcessImn() { }
function ProcessImnMarkers() { }
```

source: http://www.greggalipeau.com/sharepoint-public-facing-remove-plugin-prompt/

Answer (score 1):

Activate the plugin from the browser's plugin settings. Use `Always Activate` option. There's a similar thread on [MSDN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/appvirtualization/en-US/b1ad2b4b-dc00-432a-9667-9432e28630b6/how-to-avoid-firefox-alert-allow-xxx-site-to-run-microsoft-office) with a picture.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to disable it so this message doesn't appear for anyone. It's a publishing site; users will not be interacting with office docs at all.